# How do I set a top layout constraint for a stack view that is embedded in another stack view?

Tags: ios, storyboard, uistackview

[image]

I want to set a vertical gap of `5px` between the `give` label and the top of the `GiveLabelStack` view. When I set it using layout constraints, I get an error; see below. Stack view automatically adds a constraint of `give.top = GiveLabelStack.top`. In addition, I can't select to delete and remove the constraint.

[image: Can't delete the constraint]

On this image, I can't select the `give.top = GiveLabelStack.top` to remove.

Does anyone how I can achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried setting `GiveLabelStack`'s alignment to center?

Comment: Wow! Thanks! I've been trying for hours.

Comment: Wait. No. That doesn't work. I want to set a specific distance and not just center it vertically.

Answer (score 1):

Put the label inside its own vertical stack view (which is inside the horizontal `GiveLabelStack`). Set the vertical stack view's top layout margin to 5.

Before:

[image: before extra stack]

After:

[image: after extra stack]

Here's where you set the stack view's layout margins:

[image: setting the layout margins]